# How to cache the all html content of an iframe in angualrjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I'm new in angularjs, creating an app using angularjs, in which I'm displaying a URL using iframe. URL will content html +script + stylesheet, so this works if internet is connected, I want to handle offline scenario where i want to show iframe content when there is no internet, so basically want to cache whole content of iframe including script + stylesheet so that if there is no network then also I can still show the content. 
is there any way to cache whole iframe content including all html head, body tag and set back again in offline mode?

```
<iframe ng-src="content_url"></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you given expression and load

Comment: sorry, didn't get it? what you are asking?

Comment: can someone please help me on this

Comment: <iframe ng-src="{{content_url}}"></iframe> just try this if works